# Want to use form and styling option together

Tags: python, forms, stylesheet, web.py

I'm shifting an application from cgi to web.py. I want to use the web.form. However I've noticed that it creates a table on its own. Is it possible to style the created table (width, height, etc...)??? If yes, how???

Comment: If you don't have any restrictions on what web framework to use, I'd recommend something like Flask instead of somewhat outdated web.py. While web.py is the pioneer of small neat micro web frameworks, there appeared new ones which are better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The table is the result of form rendering, so naturally it’s placed within a `form` element. In my case it looks like this in the `login.html` template:

```
<form name="main" method="post" class="login"> 
$if not form.valid: 
    <p class="wrong">Login incorrect.</p>
$:form.render()
</form>
```

In the browser, when rendered, the form looks like this:

```
<form name="main" method="post" class="login"> 
<table> 
    <tr><th><label for="login">login</label></th><td><input type="text" id="login" name="login"/></td></tr> 
    <tr><th><label for="password">password</label></th><td><input type="password" id="password" name="password"/></td></tr> 
    <tr><th><label for="Login"></label></th><td><button id="Login" name="Login">Login</button></td></tr> 
</table> 
</form>
```

So you can apply arbitrary styling, including positioning, to this `table` using the following CSS:

```
form.login table { /* your styling */ }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!!! This helped... As for the frameworks,  I started out with cgi but got screwed when I needed session handling. I switched to web.py now. Will definitely look up flask....